# Probability of observing no sevens or elevens in any of the $10$ tosses

Tags: probability, statistics

Question: A pair of dice is tossed $10$ times in succession. What is the probability of observing no sevens and no elevens in any of the $10$ tosses?
 My approach is to do a Binomial Distribution by calculating the probability of getting something other than a $7$ or $11$ on a single toss. Also after that I should do the formula for order with replacement. Am I right? 
 The distribution part is causing me problems. So for that part am I calculating for $7$ and $11$ is $10$ choose $8$?

Comment: but the question said $10$ tosses so I figured $12$ might not be a choice here

Comment: The probability of a seven on one toss is $6/36$. On two tosses, $(6/36)^2$, etc. The probability of not getting a seven is $(1-6/36)$, on two tosses, $(1-6/36)^2$. Extrapolate for 10 rolls. Now do the same for 11's and add as ten rolls of 11 is mutually exclusive to ten rolls of 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of getting a 7 with two dice is $\frac{6}{36}$, and the probability of getting 11 is $\frac{2}{36}$, and since these are mutually exclusive, the probability of getting either one is their sum which is $\frac{8}{36}=\frac{2}{9}$.

Hence the probabiliy of not getting a 7 or 11 on a single throw is $\frac{7}{9}$.

So, not getting a 7 or 11 in any of 10 throws is $(\frac{7}{9})^{10}$

Comment: Accounting check: You can obtain a sum of 11 by throwing ...?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oh wow .... (Blush...) ... Fixed it, thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 4):

> My approach is to do a Binomial Distribution by calculating the probability of getting something other than a 7 or 11 on a single toss. Also after that I should do the formula for order with replacement. Am I right?

Right.

The probability that a Bernoulli event with probability $p$ does not occur among any of 10 independent attempts is $(1-p)^{10}$.

> The distribution part is causing me problems. So for that part am I calculating for 7 and 11 is 10 choose 8?

Wrong.

The event of tossing a sum of `7` is $\{(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2), (6,1)\}$, that is $6$ among the $36$ equally possible outcomes.

The event of tossing a sum of `11` is $\{(5,6),(6,5)\}$, which are $2$ among the $36$ equally possible outcomes.

So...

Comment: oh, that $10$ tosses obviously confused because I was so focused on that. Great analysis on breaking down my question sir